# Getting a dynamically created PDF from a URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, pdf

I have a need to aquire a pdf file generated from an aspx site.

**Backstory**:

I want to get schedueles from a website, I have succeded in getting the url to the scheduele, containing parameters. If you follow the url you will be shown a PDF stream, created by the site using given parameters.

> http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=pdf&schoolid=57240/sv-se&type=1&id=%7bD8920398-FA90-4960-BD47-69A8EFF7204D%7d&period=&week=38&mode=0&printer=1&colors=2&head=1&clock=1&foot=1&day=0&width=2480&height=3507&count=1&decrypt=0

This URL is what the site uses to get the appropriate scheduele and display it as a pdf.
Since it's not theoretically a PDF file, I can't download it as one using:

```
    Dim Downloader As New WebClient
    Downloader.DownloadFile(URL, fileName)
```

Neither can i download the content as a string using...

```
    Dim Downloader As New WebClient
    Dim Result As String = Downloader.DownloadString(URL)
```

...since it will result in an 500 Server Error due to missing parameters.

The only way of displaying the file/stream/document or whatever it's real name is, is to visit the given url through a browser. Given that, I tried to grab the PDF through a WebBrowser control. But since it "Can't display the XML page" (error displayed when navigating to the scheduele URL) I can't use that approach either.

So my question is, **How do I download this data as a PDF or How do I get this data as a Stream that i can read with StreamReader?**

**Sidenotes:**

The page uses no further client-side connections so I cannot backtrack it.
(I used Fiddler2 to track all the connections)

Using Fiddler, I can tell that the url SomethingSomething.com/Something.aspx generates a PDF and displays it. First few lines of the generated document (through Fiddler)

> %PDF-1.4
>
> %����
>
> %
>
> %wPDF by WPCubed GmbH V3.54x[0]
>
> %
>
> %
>
> 1 0 obj
>
> <>

*There are more information I can get from Fiddler about this site, so if you need it either try it yourself or ask me to add the information here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below to download the file to memory stream:

```
Dim webRes As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim memStream As New MemoryStream

Try
    Dim webReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    webReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    webRes = webReq.GetResponse

    Dim resStream As Stream = webRes.GetResponseStream

    Dim bytesRead As Integer

    Do
        Dim buffer(1023) As Byte
        bytesRead = resStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    Loop Until bytesRead = 0

Catch ex As Exception

Finally
    If webRes IsNot Nothing Then
        webRes.Close()
        webRes = Nothing
    End If

    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

End Try

' optionally save the stream into a file
memStream.WriteTo(New FileStream("d:\filename.pdf", FileMode.Create))
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need, but it does not work. After running the code as is, it outputs a file on 0 bytes. After checking ex.Message for the error it says "500 server error" It works if I paste the url in a browser (test the above if you want), But not when I use the code to grab it.

Comment: I used your link above to test the code and it worked just fine.

Comment: In fact, I tried the `Downloader.DownloadFile(URL, fileName)` code above and managed to download and save the file.

Comment: Weird! Maybe they actually had a 500 error when I tried and it had nothing to do with the method. Are the contents in the file fully functional? Can you open it and read it?

Comment: Yes... It's not in English. Looks like class time table.

Comment: Thank you it works now. I have no idea why it didn't before, might have been bad timing and that they actually did suffer from server errors. Well well, once again thank you.